# Single Celery task suspend all other Celery workers

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have a celery configuration (over django-celery) with rabbit MQ as a broker and concurrency of 20 threads.
one of the tasks is taking really long time (about an hour) to be executed and. after a few minutes that the task running all the other concurrency threads stop working until the task finish, why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Need to have multiple worker to pick up the task.
For example, environment needs to have at least 2 CPU.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency

May use celery flower to inspect the workers.